# An example of structurally unstable function

Tags: calculus, analysis, dynamical-systems

Could you please give me an example of a function with following conditions :

$f:[a,b] \to [a,b]$ is strictly increasing with two fixed points in $a$ and $b$ and without any fixed point in $(a,b)$, $f$ is $C^1$ and $f^{'}(a)=1$ or $f^{'}(b)=1$

Comment: $f(x)=x\sin\Big(\frac{\pi x}{2}\Big)$ works on $[0,1]$

Comment: If you want to use $f$ to get a function with these properties on $[a,b]$, consider $h:[0,1] \rightarrow [a,b]$ defined by $h(x)=x(b-a)+a$

Comment: Your example of $h$ does not work ! put $a=0$ and $b=1$ then $h(x)=x$ has fixed points in $ (0,1)$

Comment: Reza: $f$ is the golden ticket, not $h$. You wanna use $h$ to slightly change $f$ to make it work. Here's how. If you set $$\tilde{f}=h\circ f \circ h^{-1}$$ then $\tilde{f}:[a,b] \rightarrow [a,b]$ is what you're looking for. Here $f(x)=x\sin\Big(\frac{\pi x}{2}\Big)$ and $h(x)=x(b-a)+a$

Comment: Thanks I got it.